# Codeboxed audio recording module not detected

Tags: android, audio, titanium, appcelerator, recording

i am using Titanium SDK 2.1.2 and android SDK 2.2. I have placed the codeboxed audio recording module in

```
~/Library/Application Support/Titanium/modules/android/com.codeboxed.audiorecorder
```

But when I try to include it in ti.app.xml its not being shown in modules list. I am running sample project provided by the codeboxed team. from the following link.Please suggest where I am wrong and guide.

```
http://www.codeboxed.com/2011/08/titanium-module-for-android-audio-recording/
```

Regard:ali

Comment: Ali have u tried it with titanium sdk 1.8?

Comment: wahhab thanks for quick reply.I tried it from 2.2 to 4.3 none of them worked for me.

Comment: No no i am talking about titanium sdk i think it was not compatible after 1.8

Comment: I am using 3.0.2 as my titanium sdk that is almost latest.